# Linking Excel tables to Word when files are hosted on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, word

I am attempting to create a linked table in Word that is intended to update automatically from the source Excel document. The intent behind the linked table is to be able to quickly update all of the linked information in the word document automatically. Both files are hosted on SharePoint. I can copy and paste the table from Excel into Word using the "Link & Use Source Formatting" and the data appears as expected.

However, when you try to update the data (F9), an error pops up stating:

> Word is unable to create a link to the object you specified. Please insert the object directly into your file without creating a link.

Clicking OK replaces the data with "Error! Not a valid link."

If I look to the Link Source window, I can see that the path to the Excel document appears to be pointing to Sharepoint, albeit with %20 replacing any spaces. Is there a different link/path option that can be used for direct linking?

Comment: I think the issue may be related to the path length limits. I may need to move the documents to a folder higher in the directory to reduce the path length. I'll update the question if this change resolves the issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Sadly, no. Sorry @JohnGIS. Links would work if the path was shortened, but then re-opening the file would result in broken links again.